# Импорт класса при работе с командной строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу программу, которая работает с API. Принимает координаты и промежуток времени, затем записывает в файл погоду в этом промежутке времени по этим координатам.
Необходимо реализовать интерфейс для работы с командной строкой. Вот код модуля работы с ней:

```
import click

from weather.table_creator.local_files.local_files import LocalFiles


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command("stats")
@click.argument("lat")
@click.argument("lng")
@click.argument("start")
@click.argument("end")
def stats_cli(lat, lng, start, end):
    ob1 = LocalFiles()
    ob1.get_values(lat, lng, start, end)
    ob1.transformation()
    ob1.create_name()
    ob1.record()
```

Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю модуль через терминал, мне пишет такую ошибку:

```
(venv) D:\Documents\weather>python weather\cli\cli.py stats 56.85 60.61 2018-07-16 2018-07-18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather\cli\cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from weather.table_creator.local_files.local_files import LocalFiles
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weather'
```

При том, если я просто исполняю файл, проблемы с поиском модуля нет. В других модулях программы импорт классов осуществлялся такой же строчкой, как в этом, и всё работало.

Файловая система моей программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, данный ненайденный модуль существует и чувствует себя хорошо. Строка вызова класса из другого модуля написана PyCharm'ом автоматически. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Код модуля local_fyles:

```
import copy

from weather.table_creator.api.api import API


class LocalFiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api = API()

    def get_values(self, lat, lng, start, end):
        response = self.api.send_request(lat, lng, start, end)
        var = response.json()
        hours = var['hours']
        self.air_point = copy.deepcopy(hours)
        self.hum_point = copy.deepcopy(hours)
        self.time_point = copy.deepcopy(hours)
        for i in range(0, len(hours)):
            current_hour = hours[i]
            air = current_hour['airTemperature']
            hum = current_hour['humidity']
            time = current_hour['time']
            self.air_point[i] = air['noaa']
            self.hum_point[i] = hum['noaa']
            self.time_point[i] = time[:-9]

    def transformation(self):
        self.containing = 'дата/время;температура;влажность'
        for i in range(0, len(self.air_point)):
            self.containing = self.containing + f"\n{self.time_point[i]};{self.air_point[i]};{self.hum_point[i]}"
        return self.containing

    def create_name(self):
        self.api.lat = str(self.api.lat)
        self.api.lng = str(self.api.lng)
        self.api.lat = self.api.lat.replace('.', '')
        self.api.lng = self.api.lng.replace('.', '')
        self.api.start = self.api.start.replace('-', '')
        self.api.end = self.api.end.replace('-', '')
        self.name_file = f'{self.api.lat} {self.api.lng} {self.api.start}-{self.api.end}'
        return self.name_file

    def record(self):
        with open(f'{self.name_file}.csv', 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.containing)
            pass
        return 'успех'
```

Код модуля api:

```
import requests

from weather.table_creator.api.constants import BASE_URL, AUTHORISATION


class API:
    def __init__(self, url=BASE_URL, aut=AUTHORISATION):
        self.url = url
        self.aut = aut

    def send_request(self, lat, lng, start, end):
        self.params = {
            'params': ','.join(['humidity', 'airTemperature']),
            'lat': lat,
            'lng': lng,
            'start': f'{start} 00:00',
            'end': f'{end} 00:00'
        }
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.response = requests.get(self.url, params=self.params, headers=self.aut)
        # json_data = self.response.json()
        return self.response
```

Comment: сдвинутые значки запутали

Comment: Какие-то еще решения есть?

Comment: Поместил cli внутрь подмодуля, в котором все остальные исходники лежат. Та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы это работало.
К примеру для `wether`
Во все модули где пытаетесь импортировать `wether` до импорта `whether`

*(впринципе достаточно добавить в модуль скрипта который запускаете, но кто знает как и откуда вы эти модули еще запускать будете)*

```py
import sys

sys.path.append(r'D:\\Documents\weather') 
# ну тоесть путь к каталогу в котором находится weather. 
# Поскольку в Вашем случае, как я понял из скриншота ваш модуль находится по пути
# D:\\Documents\weather\weather то берем D:\\Documents\weather
```

> можно поупражняться с `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` но это уж сами

Для того, чтобы это корректно запустилось в PyCharm,  для конфигурации через которую запускаете скрипт установите рабочим каталогом `D:\\Documents\weather`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Жалко, что click всё-равно не работает, как надо, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: @СергейМалышев, так создайте топик с этой проблемой, думаю тоже найдется решение